# Tweener framework for c++?

Tags: c++, tweener

for ActionScript there are quite a few "tweening" frameworks to facilitate animating objects. for example TweenLite: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

it allows to animate an arbitrary object with a single line of code:

Pseudocode:
tween(myObject, 3.0f, {xpos:300});

what this line of code does is instanciating a new tweening object, which will step by step, during 3 seconds, animate the "xpos" property of 'myObject' from whatever value it currently has to 300. additionally it allows to use a variaty of different interpolation functions.

So in order to animate an object to a new point, i can write a single line of code and forget about it (the tweening object will destroy itself once it finished animating the value).

My Question is, whether there is anything comparable for c++?

I know that those languages are completely different. Anyway - i think it should be possible and would be highly convenient so if anyone knows a framework that does the trick, would be welcome :)

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have stumbled upon [libClaw's tweeners](http://libclaw.sourceforge.net/tweeners.html), and it looks promising - well documented, pretty mature and more or less alive.

I'm not sure I like the fact that it operates on `double`s only whereas I would need it primarily for `float`s and sometimes `int`s, but I don't think the double calculation and casting performance penalty should be too big...

Answer (score 3):

How about [cpptweener](http://code.google.com/p/cpptweener/). Of course which is ported from the awesome [as3 tweener library](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/).

Comment: It's looks like the cpptweener has a lot of bugs and don't works some times

Comment: Just look at comments to the function Quad::easeInOut in http://code.google.com/p/cpptweener/source/browse/trunk/src/CppTweener.cpp :) Undefined behavior almost everywhere...